# "Enjoin" vs "Adjure"

Tags: meaning, synonyms, american-english, british-english

"Enjoin" means to direct someone with emphasis and authority.
"Adjure" means to command in a serious manner.

Are the two words used in different contexts?

Comment: Well, _adjure_ isn't really used very much at all…

Comment: Adjure implies swearing.  I swear I left my keys here on the table: with that sort of oath there's no difference.  But if you only swear seriously, "By the Most High," then there's a big difference.

Answer (score 2):

*Adjure* can imply some sort of appeal to God or a command dictated with holy authority, or at the very least a very strong and earnest appeal. I would consider *enjoin* to be a somewhat weaker word with no such religious connotation. The Oxford English Dictionary notes that *enjoin* "*is more authoritative than direct, and less imperious than command*" (citing Samuel Johnson).